# The meaning of "make it as"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> NANCY: I know that if you can't take criticism you'll never make it as a writer.

I wonder what the meaning of that sentence is. Does it mean if you can't take criticism then  you'll never become a writer? If my guess is right then how can "it" refers to an human? 
I found another sentence. it is "If you're not a reader, you'll never make it as a writer"
Can "it" in those sentences refer to some writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "make it" means "succeed".

So, if you can't take criticism, you'll never succeed as a writer.

Consider:

> We only have ten minutes to finish the climb.  We'll never make it.

So, yes, your understanding was correct.

Answer (score 0):

**make it as** in this situation means **become successful**. ie: "...become successful as a writer"

it is [informal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/make+it) (see definition 1 under *make it*)